# Going back to a stopped job

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, ipython

```
wim@wim-zenbook:~$ ipython
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: x = 'potato'

In [2]: # I'm about to press ctrl+z

In [3]: 
[1]+  Stopped                 ipython
wim@wim-zenbook:~$ # how do I get back to my ipython?!
wim@wim-zenbook:~$ bg
[1]+ ipython &
wim@wim-zenbook:~$ # ummm...

[1]+  Stopped                 ipython
wim@wim-zenbook:~$ logout
There are stopped jobs.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 / gnome-terminal and I bumped ctrl+z in ipython.  How do I get back?

Comment: Try fg command, to forground your work.

Comment: It worked.  Would you like to post that as an answer, or should I delete the question?